# Android Carbon library нужно убрать дефолтную анимацию нажатия кнопки

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Использую библиотеку [Carbon](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon). В этой библиотеке при нажатии на carbon.widget.Button происходит установленная по дефолту анимация. Эту анимацию нужно убрать. В документации нашёл атрибуты `carbon_inAnimation="none"` и `carbon_outAnimation="none"`, но они не дают результата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог атрибут `app:carbon_rippleColor="@null"`